ODE with general form
We know that the the general form of ODE of the $n$-th order  is $$f(x,y,y',y'',\dots , y^{(n)})=0$$
Also, the general form of first partial differential equation (PDE) $$f\big( x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n, \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_n}\big)=0$$
I was thinking if we can have a general form for ODE. I checked some of ODE's books but I could not find any thing about  that. Any idea?

ODEs can be linear or nonlinear. A nonlinear ODE might involve terms like $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 $ or $\sin(\frac{dy}{dx})$ so a general ( “One-Size-Fits-All”) form must allow for all kinds of nonlinearity. But , I am not really sure if this can be done.

The general form of an ODE of the $n$'th order should be
$f(x,y,y',y'', \ldots,, y^{(n)}) = 0$.

@RobertIsrael, how about the general form of ODE? Can we such form ?

I don't understand.  Every ODE has some order, i.e. it depends on some finite number of derivatives of $y$, so $f(x,y,y',y'',\ldots,y^{(n)}) = 0$ is the general form.

@RobertIsrael I meant can we have general from for DE works for both ODE and PDE

So why don't you write what you mean?

Based on the discussion above, it seems the question is to write a general form of a PDE. One way of writing general PDEs is by using multiindices, which allow one to record mixed partial derivatives in a compact fashion.
Fix $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ as the order and $d\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ as the dimension, and consider $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_d)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}^d$, so that $\alpha$ is an $d$-tuple of nonnegative integers. For $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}^d$, define
$$|\alpha|=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_d\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}.$$
Then for $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ a function (that is sufficiently smooth) define a new function
$$
\partial^\alpha \phi: \mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}, \partial^\alpha \phi(x_1,x_2,...,x_d) = \dfrac{\partial^{|\alpha|}\phi}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}\partial x_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots \partial x_d^{\alpha_d}}(x_1,x_2,...,x_d),
$$
Note that by using $\partial^\alpha$ for $|\alpha|\leq n$, one can express all mixed partial derivatives up to order $n$.
Denote by $N(d,n)$ the number of distinct multiindices $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|\leq n$ (a straightforward count gives $N(d,n)=\begin{pmatrix}n+d\\n\end{pmatrix}$; see e.g. How can I show the cardinality of the set $A_m=\{\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n: |\alpha|\leq m\}$ is $\#A_m=\binom{m+n}{m}$?). Thus specifying a function $F:\mathbb{R}^{d+N(d,n)}\to$ specifies a unique partial differential equation:

Solve
\begin{align*}
F(&\underbrace{x_1,x_2,...,x_d}_{=x},\\
&\phi(x),\\
&\partial^{(1,0,...,0)}\phi(x),\partial^{(0,1,0,...,0)}\phi(x),...,\partial^{(0,0,...,0,1)}\phi(x),\\
&\partial^{(2,0,...,0)}\phi(x), \partial^{(1,1,0,...,0)}\phi(x),...,\partial^{(0,0,...,0,2)}\phi(x),\\
&..., \\
&\partial^{(n,0,...,0)}\phi(x),\partial^{(n-1,1,...,0)}\phi(x),...,\partial^{(0,0,...,n)}\phi(x)
)=0.
\end{align*}
for $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$.

(Note that the same PDE may be specified by different $F$'s, and that if $d=1$, this formalism coincides with the general form of an ODE.)
This can further be generalized of course (for instance one might have an additional parameter space etc.); but it seems for the purposes of this question this form is sufficiently general.

As an example, the heat equation (thus $n=2$) in $d=1+3$ dimensions is specified by $F$ a row vector all of whose entries are zero except the $\partial^{(1,0,0,0)}$ entry is $-1$, and $\partial^{(0,2,0,0)}$, $\partial^{(0,0,2,0)}$, $\partial^{(0,0,0,2)}$ entries are $1$.
